# Format SDHC / microSDHC card as SD / microSD?

Tags: formatting, sd-card, mobile-phone

Is this possible?

Details: I got a 4 GB microSDHC card for a Nokia phone that only supports
- max 2GB
- microSD

Since the card is microSD**HC**, it is detected but can not be reformatted by the phone.

Note: I can access and format the card without a problem from a Windows PC, using the supplied SD adapter. I tried reformatting in both FAT and FAT32 without any different result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this possible?

In a word, no.

The SDHC standard is using a higher number of blocks per cluster than the SD standard. If the reader doesn't support this standard, then you can't use the card.